# How to set breakpoints for a single window in VSCode

Tags: vscode-debugger

I'm developing in Flutter/Dart. I have a chat app, with multiple browser windows open, as multiple chat users. I want to be able to debug just one of the windows.

Breakpoints are triggered for all windows now. Is there a way to set breakpoints on a per-window basis?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - run the browser in debug mode for the chat user I am interested in, for the others run in release mode.